# Что означает модификатор [In, Out] в C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Смотрел исходники и обнаружил, что один из аргументов метода `Read` класса `FileStream` имеет модификатор `[In, Out]` .

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
        public override int Read([In, Out] byte[] array, int offset, int count) {
}
```

Что означает этот модификатор?

Если верить MSDN, то он используется для взаимодействия с COM, но вроде COM взаимодействия в данном методе нет.

Comment: Направление движения данных. Вы ему на вход массив, а метод его меняет. В MSDN сплошь и рядом оно для WinAPI

Comment: А через ref такого поведения нельзя добиться?

Comment: А кто ж его знает, я на .NET не пишу...

Comment: @iluxa1810: А `byte[]` — reference type, с ним можно передавать данные и так. Смысл в том, что COM нужно дать подсказку, разрешается для эти данные читать (`[In]`) или писать (`[Out]`).

Comment: @iluxa1810, начнем с того, что это не модификаторы, а атрибуты. В C# есть модификаторы параметров `out` и `ref`, что может Вас смутить, если вы где-то про них пытались читать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `OutAttribute` - показывает, что требуется маршалинг данных из
>   вызываемого объекта в вызывающий.

---

> `InAttribute` - показывает, маршалинг каких данных необходимо выполнить
>   при передаче от вызывающего объекта — вызываемому, но не обратно.

Данные атрибуты могут быть применены к параметрам. Аргументы `InAttribute` и `OutAttribute` являются необязательными. Эти атрибуты поддерживается только для COM-взаимодействия и вызова неуправляемого кода.

Подробнее можно прочитать на MSDN:

1. [OutAttribute - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [InAttribute - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.inattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Обратите внимание на **Заметки** и **Примеры**, перейдя по ссылкам.